# How to add Dummy Data in Firestore using cloud functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to add dummy values in firestore using cloud functions and im using http trigger to pass the number of dummy values that i want to create, this doesnt work

```
exports.addDummyUsers = functions.https
.onRequest((request,response)=>{

    let dbb=admin.firestore();
    let counter = request.query.counter;

     for(let i=0;i<counter;i++){
        dbb.collection('Users').doc('Lone').set({
            email: 'Dummy',
            name: 'Dummy',
            phoneNumber: 'Dummy'
        });
        console.log("Dummy " + counter + ' added');
     }

    response.send(counter + ' Dummy Values Created!');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated Answer following Frank's comment below:**

You want to create several Firestore documents in parallel. In your case (no need for an atomic write) the best is to use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

You should wait that the set of asynchronous operations is completed before sending back the response, i.e. wait that the single Promise returned by `Promise.all()` resolves.

So, the following should work:

```
exports.addDummyUsers = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

        let dbb = admin.firestore();
        let counter = request.query.counter;

        const promises = []

        for (let i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
            promises.push(
                dbb.collection('Users').doc('Lone' + i).set({
                    email: 'Dummy',
                    name: 'Dummy',
                    phoneNumber: 'Dummy'
                })
            )
        }

        return Promise.all(promises)
            .then(resultsArray => {
                response.send(counter + ' Dummy Values Created!');
            })
            .catch(error => {

               //Watch the official video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA&t=1s&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkPZHe41m4jfAxUi0JjLgSM&index=3

            });

});
```

---

**Original answer:**

*See Frank's comment below on why it is better to use `Promise.all()` in any case.*

*See also the following remark in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes): "...Batched writes perform better than serialized writes **but not better than parallel writes**.*

You should either use a [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) (if you have less than 500 documents to write) or use `Promise.all()`.

You should also wait that the set of asynchronous operations is completed before sending back the response.

So the following should work:

```
exports.addDummyUsers = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

    let dbb = admin.firestore();
    let counter = request.query.counter;

    if (counter < 500) {
        //Use batched write
        let batch = dbb.batch();

        for (let i = 0; i < counter; i++) {

            const docRef = dbb.collection('Users').doc('Lone' + i);  //Here you need to create different doc reference. E.g. use the value of i
            batch.set(docRef, {
                email: 'Dummy',
                name: 'Dummy',
                phoneNumber: 'Dummy'
            });
        }

        return batch.commit()
            .then(() => {
                response.send(counter + ' Dummy Values Created!');
            })
            .catch(error => {
                //Watch the official video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA&t=1s&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkPZHe41m4jfAxUi0JjLgSM&index=3
            });


    } else {
        //Use Promise.all
        const promises = []

        for (let i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
            promises.push(
                dbb.collection('Users').doc('Lone' + i).set({
                    email: 'Dummy',
                    name: 'Dummy',
                    phoneNumber: 'Dummy'
                })
            )
        }

        return Promise.all(promises)
            .then(resultsArray => {
                response.send(counter + ' Dummy Values Created!');
            })
            .catch(error => {

                //Watch the official video

            });

    }

});
```

Comment: I'd recommend against using a batch here, as there's no dependency between the documents being written. Running the writes individually and collecting with a `Promise.all()` allows then to run in parallel, potentially speeding up execution.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks, Frank, for your sound advice. Answer adapted!

Comment: I am so glad that you helped, I really appreciate it, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Renauds answer is good and complete but just to simplify everything a bit, the following will work but will possibly timeout depending on the value of the counter.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.addDummyUsers = functions.https.onRequest(async (request,response)=>{

let dbb=admin.firestore();
let counter = request.query.counter;
let userName = ""

for(let i=0;i<counter;i++){

    userName = "Lone" + i.toString().padStart(4, '0') // pad to length 4 with leading zeros
    await dbb.collection('Users').doc(userName).set({
        email: 'Dummy',
        name: 'Dummy',
        phoneNumber: 'Dummy'
    });
    console.log("Dummy " + counter + ' added');
 }

response.send(counter + ' Dummy Values Created!');
});
```

The problems in your code are as follows:

In the line `dbb.collection('Users').doc('Lone').set({`

you do not add i to to doc name so you keep overwriting the same doc "Lone". Renaud fixed this.

Secondly there is no await, so the cloud function will finish before the documents are added so some of the documents will not be added. The async in the

```
exports.addDummyUsers = functions.https.onRequest(async (request,response)=>{
```

then means you can use await and this means that the code will wait until each document has been added. this is much more efficient if you do batch writes but as Renaud pointed out, 500 writes (or the combination of adds, updates or deletes) is the limit.

You could also do the same by doing the batch writes inside a loop if counter is greater than 500.

Also, to make the sorting look more logical in the firebase console, I have padded the counter value to 4 (obviously this would not be enough if the counter was passed as 10000)

To change the timeout do the following

This is by default set to 60 seconds on cloud functions although this can be changed by using runWith and the timeout and memory options if you need to increase runtime memory.

```
const runtimeOpts = {
  timeoutSeconds: 300,
  memory: '1GB'
}

exports.addFirestoreData = functions.wunWith(runtimeOpts).https.onCall(async data => {
```

One other note. You need to be careful that you do not create hotspots in your data by not using automatically generated document ids.

Your users are going to be all in the same area as the names are all Lone0001,Lone002 etc. which will mean that accesses will clash a lot and therefore reduce performance.

The point of the automatically generated document Ids is that they are designed to avoid hotspots. This discusses best practices https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/best-practices

Comment: In your code won't the for-loop finish before each individual write is finished, as the `await` in the loop only affects that statement? I'd expect you to need a `Promise.all(...)` as Renaud mentioned in his answer.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I believe this code will work correctly, although I do bow to your superior knowledge. I did some tests and this managed about 316 record adds before the 60 second timeout was reached. If the console.log was removed it did over 700 document adds in 60 seconds. The for loop will not increment until the add completed.

Comment: Interesting, it indeed waits in this simple example: `const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
var count = 0;
for (let i=0; i < 10; i++) {
  await wait(500)  
}
console.log("done");` TIL more about `await` in a for loop. :)

Comment: I am so glad that you helped, I really appreciate it, thank you

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I will admit there are many cases where the await will not work in a For loop but in this case, it is easy to read code and does work. And as a not very experienced javascript programmer, who has been forced at no notice to start writing cloud functions and work with firebase (which I do like a lot), simple is what I have had to do.